# How do I make a checkbox invisible but keep the "focus" on?

Tags: css, reactjs

This is my markup.

```
   // handling checkbox state
   ...

   // handling rendering

   <div ref={ref}>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked={isActive}>
      <CustomSVGCheckbox hasHover={hasHover} isActive={isActive} />
      <label htmlFor="checkbox">Otional label</label>
    </div>
```

Essentially I would like to visually hide the HTML checkbox and fake it with CustomSVGCheckbox and have focus on it.

Hiding the checkbox seem to be working with the styles:

```
      position: 'absolute',
      opacity: 0,
      zIndex: -1,
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
      overflow: 'hidden',
```

But how do I make the focus working around my SVG checkbox? I would like to customize the focus outline as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `:focus-within` pseudo-class ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within), [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within)):

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

/* If any child of this label gets focus, show these styles */
label:focus-within CustomSVGCheckbox {
  outline: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999vw;
}

/* styles below this line are just to create a "custom checkbox" and are not needed for the solution above */

CustomSVGCheckbox {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
}

CustomSVGCheckbox::before {
  content: '\2713';
}

:checked + CustomSVGCheckbox::before {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<label ref={ref}>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked={isActive} />
  <CustomSVGCheckbox hasHover={hasHover} isActive={isActive}></CustomSVGCheckbox>
  Optional input
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really what I want, I want only the checkbox to show focus style. The focus now is on both. Checkbox and Label

Comment: @karolis2017, sorry, I meant for this to be a template that you could adapt to your purposes.  Let me update the code to do exactly as you say.